# Hive count over partition by in case when

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have two queries:

```
select count(*) over (partition by col1) from t1
```

and

```
select case when count(*) over (partition by col1) >1 then 1 else 0 end from t1
```

The first one works fine. The second however raises an error:

```
Invalid column reference 'count': (possible column names are: <all columns in t1>)
```

Putting any column name instead of `*` in `count` gives the same behaviour.

What causes the problem? I haven't found any restrictions in dosc for `case when` and `over partition by` together.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do that in Hive, but lookup QUALIFY.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-7660

Comment: @deusxmach1na I dont't think it's the same - the qualify is somewhat a where clause. Here I just want values in a select.

Comment: maths to the rescue `select ROUND((count(*) over (partition by col1) - 1) / count(*) over (partition by col1)) from t1`

Comment: @deusxmach1na Thanks, that's clever. However, I'm still curious why it doesn't work directly...

Comment: If I had to guess it's a feature they haven't implemented yet or a bug.  
BTW I just tried it with IF and it works: `select IF(count(*) over (partition by col1) > 1, 1, 0)  from t1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select COUNT(CASE WHEN >1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) over (partition by col1) from t1;
```

Comment: It doesn't work and I don't see why it should: the `>` is binary operator, so it needs something on both sides.